# 3ph 2l inverter simulation with SPWM

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

Here is a code for a simple model of three phase two level inverter with constant DC voltage source and three phase RL load.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy import signal

##Parameters
#time axis
starting_time = 0 #[s]
step_time = .2e-6 #[s]
ending_time = 50e-3 #[s]
#PWM modulator
m = 0.85 #[-] modulation index
f_e = 1e3 #[Hz] electrical frequency
f_sw = 40e3 #[Hz] switching frequency
#DC-link
Vdc = 800 #[V] DC-link voltage
#load
R = 0.5 #[ohm]
L = 400e-6 #[H] self-inductance
K = 0 #inductances coupling coefficient, <1
M = K*L #[H] mutual inductance

##Functions

def ref(time, amplitude, frequency, phase):
    ref = amplitude*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*time + phase)
    return ref

def triangle(time, frequency):
    triangle = signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*frequency*time, 0.5)
    return triangle

def SPWM(mod, carrier):
    if mod >= carrier:
        d = 1
    if mod < carrier:
        d = 0
    return d

def system(t, y):
    
    mod1 = ref(t, m, f_e, 0)
    mod2 = ref(t, m, f_e, 2/3*np.pi)
    mod3 = ref(t, m, f_e, 4/3*np.pi)
    carrier = triangle(t, f_sw)
    d1 = SPWM(mod1, carrier)
    d2 = SPWM(mod2, carrier)
    d3 = SPWM(mod3, carrier)
    v1_gnd = d1*Vdc
    v2_gnd = d2*Vdc
    v3_gnd = d3*Vdc
    vgnd_n = -(v1_gnd + v2_gnd + v3_gnd)/3
    v1 = v1_gnd + vgnd_n 
    v2 = v2_gnd + vgnd_n 
    v3 = v3_gnd + vgnd_n 
    v12 = v1 - v2 
    v23 = v2 - v3 
    v13 = v1 - v3
    i1 = 1/(L*L+L*M-2*M*M)*((L+M)*y[0]-M*y[1]-M*y[2])
    i2 = 1/(L*L+L*M-2*M*M)*((L+M)*y[1]-M*y[0]-M*y[2])
    i3 = 1/(L*L+L*M-2*M*M)*((L+M)*y[2]-M*y[0]-M*y[1])
    dl1dt = -R*i1+v1
    dl2dt = -R*i2+v2
    dl3dt = -R*i3+v3

    return dl1dt, dl2dt, dl3dt

dt1 = datetime.now()

time = np.arange(starting_time,ending_time,step_time)
time = np.round(time,9)

sol = solve_ivp(system, [0,ending_time], [0,0,0], t_eval = time, method = 'LSODA', max_step = 1/50/f_sw, rtol = 1e-6, atol = 1e-6)
t = sol.t
l1 = sol.y[0]
l2 = sol.y[1]
l3 = sol.y[2]
i1 = 1/(L*L+L*M-2*M*M)*((L+M)*l1-M*l2-M*l3)
i2 = 1/(L*L+L*M-2*M*M)*((L+M)*l2-M*l1-M*l3)
i3 = 1/(L*L+L*M-2*M*M)*((L+M)*l3-M*l1-M*l2)

dt2 = datetime.now()
print(dt2-dt1)
```

I need to consider an high switching frequency (max 40kHz), so sampling should be around 1/40e3/50 to get good results.

At the moment, with my PC I'm only able to simulate 50ms in around 1 min. I was wondering if there's a way to optimize this problem and speed up the simulation. Ideally I would like to be able to simulate minutes of inverter operation in reasonable time.

I tested that using a `for` loop with fixed time step and explicit integration method speeds up the simulation (not that much). Is there something better?

Comment: Cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77456067/python3-3ph-2l-inverter-simulation-with-spwm